# Compiling a basic C /GDI+ program (beginner question)

Tags: compilation

I am just trying to compile this simple example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533895(VS.85).aspx

what needs to be done , in order to compile and run this?

- I have installed platform sdk
- set the correct paths for include and lib dirs
- tried different c compilers (visual c++ , c-free , dev-C++ )

first I was getting gdiplus.h not found error. After fixing that

these are the errors:

> 1>E:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows XP SP2\Include\specstrings.h(334) : warning C4005: '__reserved' : macro redefinition
>
> 1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\sal.h(702) : see previous definition of '__reserved'
>
> 1>E:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows XP SP2\Include\specstrings.h(341) : warning C4005: '__checkReturn' : macro redefinition
>
> 1>        e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\sal.h(703) : see previous definition of '__checkReturn'

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for visual studio: add in the Linker settings->command line "gdiplus.lib" to the 'Additional Options'

Comment: Thanks but where exactly are these linker settings

Comment: Ok I added gpiplus.lib, to linker settings. Now I am getting this: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PostQuitMessage@4 referenced in function "long __stdcall WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)

Comment: New Project->Win32 Project->Windows applicaton/emtpy project/->finish
add new item->main.cpp->paste the example code, build it.
if this do not work something is wrong with the Platform SDK path settings.